# Incompatible parameter types in lambda expression

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, functional-programming, weak-references

Considering this code:

```
Map<C1, C2> map;
C1 key;
C2 value;
```

Why does this work:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> value)
```

And this doesn't?

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, () -> value)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the method [computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) has the following signature:

```
default V computeIfAbsent(K key,
                          Function<? super K,? extends V> mappingFunction)
```

so it expects a `Function`, which is a function interface that expects an argument and returns a value. Whereas `() -> value`, receives no arguments and produces a value (*e.g.*, [Supplier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html)).

Answer (score -1):

In addition to @[dreamcrash's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67028529/1366871) answer, there is a way to *supply* an entry to a `Map` if the key is absent.

It has been added in [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) and is called `Map#putIfAbsent`

And this would exactly work like what you had in mind

```
map.putIfAbsent("key", ((Supplier<String>) () -> "value").get());
```

However this is a bit complicated and you'd prefer using directly the `value`

```
map.putIfAbsent("key", "value");
```